# Is it possible to hide the hover value displayed on chart in react-chart-js2

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-chartjs-2

I have implemented a pie chart using react-chartjs-2 library. I am facing issue in showing/hiding the tooltip that comes when we hover on the chart.

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
import {Pie} from 'react-chartjs-2';

class PieChart extends React.Component {
    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);
        this.state = {
        };
}

render() {
    let color = ['#1f77b4', '#ff7f0e'];

    let cTDcolor = {
        "Being Assessed": "#4472c4",
        "Not Started": "#ed7d31",
        "No Data": "#a5a5a5"
    };

    let chartData = [], label = [], colorCTDArray = [];
    let keyAttr = this.props.keyAttribute;
    let valueAttr = this.props.valueAttribute;
    const priorityArray = ["Low","Medium","High","Pending"];
    if(this.props.chartSeries != undefined && this.props.chartSeries != null) {
        this.props.chartSeries.sort(function(a, b){
            var firstPrio = priorityArray.indexOf(a.complexity);
            var secPrio = priorityArray.indexOf(b.complexity);
            return firstPrio -secPrio 
            });
        this.props.chartSeries.map(function(element) { 
            chartData.push(element[valueAttr]);
            label.push(element[keyAttr]);
        });
    }

    //Sorting colors...
    
    label.map(function(item) {
      colorCTDArray.push(cTDcolor[item]);
    });
    const options = {
        legend: {
          labels: {
            boxWidth: 12
          }
        },
        plugins:  {
          datalabels: {
            display: false
          }  
        }
    };
  
    let data;
        data = {
            labels: label,
            datasets: [{
                data: chartData,
                backgroundColor: colorCTDArray,
                hoverBackgroundColor: colorCTDArray
            }]
        };
    return (
        <div>
                <Pie data={data} height={this.props.height} options={options} />
        </div>
        );
    }
}

PieChart.propTypes = {
    chartSeries: React.PropTypes.array,
    height: React.PropTypes.number,
    color: React.PropTypes.array,
    keyAttribute: React.PropTypes.string,
    valueAttribute: React.PropTypes.string,
    isCTD: React.PropTypes.bool,
    isPie: React.PropTypes.bool
};

export default PieChart;
```

It is displaying like above with the dummy data passed from UI side:
[image]

I don't want to show the tool tip `No Data` on hover of chart. It will be okay if it can hide for every state variable, or just for `No Data`. Both can serve my objective. I am not sure because of which object it can be displayed/hide. Can someone please help me to hide the tooltip.

Comment: Do you want to hide tooltip for every state or for No Data only?

Comment: It's ok to hide tooltip for every state.